# Not able to register temp table while using hive context in Spark-shell

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am running below code , but the a void dataframe is being return while registering a temp table in hive context .

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in your interpretation of the code it self.

reg

> but the a void dataframe is being return while registering a temp
>   table in hive context .

Your code first creates the dataframe and registeres it with temporary table and returns the result of the registerTempTable and assigns it to df3. **You are not assigning the result of read.json() to df3.**

If you want the Datafrme and Temp table both, 
then you should follow Vijay mentioned.

**Meaning of your code:**
(Create a dataframe and register it as temporary table tweet and assign returned value of registerTempTable to df3)
So, df3 will have returned value of registerTempTable, not read.json.

**Meaning of Vijay's code:**
//Create a dataframe and assign it to df3
val df3 = hctx.read.json("/development/sr3/data/test/testweet.json")

//register the df3 to a temp table
df3.registerTempTable("tweet")

Do either of this:

```
val df3 = hctx.read.json("/development/sr3/data/test/testweet.json"); df3.registerTempTable("tweet")
```

OR

`val df3 = hctx.read.json("/development/sr3/data/test/testweet.json").registerTempTable("tweet").show()` which returns the final DF. again, but does not make sense.

Overall, i hope you got the point. You need to ensure the the return that you have finally is important

Answer (score 0):

can you try this

```
val df3 = hctx.read.json("/development/sr3/data/test/testweet.json")
df3.registerTempTable("tweet")
sqlContext.sql("SELECT count(*) FROM tweet")
```